# Is there a term for a mathematical operation that yields a result which is of a different type than the type of its operands?

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology

> Is there a term for a mathematical operation that yields a result which is of a different type than the type of its operands?

To try and explain what I mean, consider what happens when we multiply or divide a real number by another real number; the result is also a real number. For example;

$$
1 \times 1 = 1
$$

If however, we multiply or divide an imaginary number by another imaginary number, the result is not an imaginary number, but instead a real number. Again, an example;

$$
2i \times 2i = -4
$$

What is this phenomenon (for lack of a better word) called, where the type of the result of the operation — a real number in this case — is different from the type of the two operands which are supplied to the operation — both imaginary numbers in this case?

I'm thinking some term which includes either of the words "heterogeneous" or "homogeneous".

Comment: Please put your whole question in the post. Letters don't start on the envelope, posts don't start on the title line.

Comment: The same could be said for irrationals.  $\frac {\pi}{\pi}=1$ which is not irrational.  And for negative integer.  $-2 - (-7) = 5$ which is not a negative integer.    For for that matter if we define $A = \{3, \pi, -6\}$ then $3\times 6 = 18$ which is not in $A$.  I think we need to distinguish when our set is "significant" rather than incomplete subsets that are part of a whole but defined to not be the whole.  $2i$ is an imaginary number but more importantly it is a complex number.  But so is $4$. (OTOH $b^q; b,q\in\mathbb Q$ *is* a good example of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You would say, in this example, that the set of imaginary numbers is *not closed* under multiplication. This is the negation of a very important type of property: closure properties. We would say the real numbers *are closed* under multiplication.

Comment: "not closed" is weaker than the property the OP describes: not closed means there exist inputs such that the output do not lie in the set. OP wants *every* input to have this property.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context, but your particular example seems to be a scalar valued vector product, possibly a bilinear form. If the result can be a vector as well it would be a vector valued vector product.

Answer (score 0):

I also think (as @Malady said) that the best term for this is "closure" property.

For example, the set of even numbers $2\mathbb{N}$ is *closed* under multiplication and *closed* under addition since (for $k,h \in \mathbb{N}$):

$$2k + 2h = 2(k+h) \in 2\mathbb{N}$$

$$(2k)(2h) = 2(2kh) \in 2\mathbb{N}$$

**however**, the set of odd numbers $2\mathbb{N}+1$ is not  *closed* under addition since:

$$2k+1 + 2h+1 = 2(k+h+1) \notin 2\mathbb{N}+1.$$

Comment: Nitpick:  "imaginary" number is not the same as "complex" (in much the same way "negative integer" is not that same as "integer" and "irrational" is not the same as "real").  $4$ is not imaginary (nor is, say, $5 + 2i$).  Only numbers of the form $0 + ki$ are imaginary (so $0$ is FWIW).  A good example of something not closed is exponentiation on positive rationals.

Comment: @fleablood you are right, it turns out imaginary numbers only have the form $bi$ with $b$ real, I always thought imaginary and complex was the same!